# Fragment onStart Activated without being in current Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have TabLayout using 4 fragment, a1, a2, a3, a4,
The problem is when I enter a1 Fragment, a2 Fragment activated too, and when I go to a2 Fragment it already Activated, it seems like this => a1(Entered>Activated) - a2 (Activated) - a3(Not Activated) - a4 (Not Activated)
Another case:
a1(Not Activated) - a2 (Activated) - a3(Entered>Activated) - a4 (Activated)
It's hard to explain it, I think my code is working properly, and why I have an issue like this, how to fix it?

Comment: this is working as intended, the Fragments left and Right to the currently selected tab are activated

Comment: How to fix it? @DominikWuttke

Comment: you can override `setUserVisibleHint` to check if fragment activated

Comment: @huang12345 wow it works like charms, Thank you so much chang, I can mark Your answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override `setUserVisibleHint` to check if fragment activated

```
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser) {

            //this Fragment is visible 

        } else {

            //this Fragment is invisible

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't see exactly what is the error.

The code is working as it should be. When you are using TabLayout, the two adjacent fragments to the one selected are activated as well.

Comment: But when I use Toast in a2 Fragment, it activated when I enter the a1 Fragment it really annoying

Comment: But that's just how a ViewPager works. If that's not what you want, then maybe you should consider different options. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51296050/9252689

Comment: example I have 3 Fragment, Home - News - Profile, I had validate Profile will Intent to another activity Login if user Doesn't login before, so When I enter to News Fragment it will Intent to Login Activity, doesn't it weird?

Comment: It may be weird for what you are trying to do, maybe your code should only run when that specific tab is selected, but TabLayout does this to improve transitions, so when you swipe between the tabs, the user won't experience lags and things like that.